# Want to sent mail to different mail id's of a user using Laravel Mail Notifcation

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.4

**Company.php**

```
public function routeNotificationForMail() {
    return $this->office_mail;
}
```

This is my company modal where i can specify only one mail id.but I want to send mail to 2 mail id's

**App\Notifications\JobApplication.php**

```
public function toMail($notifiable) {
    $message = 'A candidate applied for your job posting, ' . $this->job['job_title'];
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line($message)
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

when a candidate apply for a company's job posting, A mail should be sent to the company's office mail address and company's login mail address. ie)my company table contans email field and office_mail field

I have seen this link "https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15694". but not clear about how to use htis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function routeNotificationForMail() {
    return [$this->office_mail, $this->email];
}
```

can return as an array